# Python : How to interpret the result of logistic regression by sm.Logit

Tags: python, statistics, regression

When I run a logistic regression using [`sm.Logit`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Logit.html) (from the [`statsmodel`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html) library), part of the result looks like this:

```
Pseudo R-squ.:                  0.4335

Log-Likelihood:                -291.08

LL-Null:                       -513.87

LLR p-value:                 2.978e-96
```

How could I explain the significance of the model? Or say, the ability of explaining? Which indicator should I use? I have searched online and there isn't much information about `Pseudo R2` and `LLR pvalue`. I'm confused and I don't know how to judge the performance of my model based on these numbers

Comment: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-what-are-pseudo-r-squareds/ statsmodels uses the McFadden's not adjusted version for pseudo-R2.

Answer (score 11):

From [Hands-On Machine Learning for Algorithmic Trading](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/hands-on-machine-learning/9781789346411/):

> - `Log-Likelihood`: this is the maximized value of the log-likelihood function.
> - `LL-Null`: this is the result of the maximized log-likelihood function when only an intercept is included. It forms the basis for the pseudo-[image: R^2] statistic and the Log-Likelihood Ratio (LRR) test (see below)
> - `pseudo`-[image: R^2]: this is a substitute of the familiar [image: R^2] available under least squares. It is computed based on the ratio of the maximized log-likelihood function for the null model `m0` and the full model `m1` as follows:

[image: pseudo-R^2]
<sub>(source: [googleapis.com](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=%5Crho%5E2%20%3D%201%20-%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Clog%20%5Cmathcal%7BL%7D(m_1%5E*)%7D%7B%5Clog%20%5Cmathcal%7BL%7D(m_0%5E*)%7D))</sub>

> The values vary from 0 (when the model does not improve the likelihood) to 1 (where the model fits perfectly and the log-likelihood is maximized at 0). Consquently, higher values indicate a better fit.
>
> - `LLR`: The LLR test generally compares a more restricted model and is computed as:

[image: llr]

> The null hypothesis is that the restricted model performs better but a low p-value suggests that we can reject this hypothesis and prefer the full model over the null model. This is similar to the F-test for linear regression (where can also use the LLR test when we estimate the model using MLE).
>
> - `z-statistic`: plays the same role as the t-statistic in the linear regression output and is equally computed as the ratio of the coefficient estimate and its standard error.
> - `p-values`: these indicate the probability of observing the test statistic assuming the null hypothesis [image: H0] that the population coefficient is zero.

As you can see (and the way I understand it), many of these metrics are counterparts to those of the linear regression case. Furthermore, as Rose already point out, I would recommend checking [the statsmodel documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20220331180133/https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html).

Comment: For a better explanation about the z-statistic, I recommend [this post](http://logisticregressionanalysis.com/1577-what-are-z-values-in-logistic-regression/)

Answer (score -3):

**p-value :** this will allow you to test your null hypothesis. A low p-value (< 0.05) indicates that you can reject the null hypothesis.
If you are not familiar with it I suggest : https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability/significance-tests-one-sample/tests-about-population-mean/v/hypothesis-testing-and-p-values

**r-squared :** measure of how close the data are to the fitted regression line.  It represents the percentage of the variable variation that is explained by a linear model.

*Maybe if you were to give us more details about the hypotheses you have made and the context of your regression, we would be able to help more.*

The other 2 (log likelihood and LL Null), I am less familiar with, but here are some ressources to have a look at that might help:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function
http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html
https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But I think that your definition of **p-value** and **r-squared** are about the normal regression, while I'm doing a **logistic regression**. Does the LLR p-value has the same meaning in the one in normal regression? I mean, can I say that my model is significant if I see the LLR P-value is lower than 0.05?

Comment: I'm just doing a normal logistic regression by using `sm.Logit`. I think that the null hypothesis is just the normal one, say like _H0: Model is not significant_.

Comment: Normally the p-values in a logistic regression can be interpreted the same way as other p-values. Let's say your H0 is something like : There is no relationship between 2 variables. If the p-value is less than small threshold, then you can reject H0, which means that you decide that there is a relationship between your 2 variables.In your case, it is large, so you can't reject H0, which states that there is no relationship between the variabes. However, this does not prove that H0 is true, but it just means you can't reject it ;)

Comment: Thanks again! But the p-value in my case is: LLR p-value: 2.978e-96, is it still large? I think that this p value is quite small... Can I reject the null hypothesis for the reason that p value is lower than 0.05(threshold)? I'm just not quite sure whether the way of intepreting LLR p-value is the same as other p-values, like the one in linear regressions:)

Comment: oh yes you are right, it is very small sorry :) i've misread. The LLR p-value is associated with a likelihood test, which compares 2 models, one which reflects the null hypothesis, and another one. The way you interpret the p-value is the same in the sense that you reject H0 if its less than the chosen threshold.